# Is there any way to send an asset to many wallet addresses at once (batch)?

Tags: transactions, assets

so I need to distribute a Stellar Asset to multiple wallet addresses.
Is there any way so I can do it at once, maybe 10-20 wallet at once?

Answer (score 1):

Stellar allows [adding up to 100 operations](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html) (payments in your case) to a single transaction. You can use this feature to send payment batches.

But you need to check for each account that

1. The account exists on the ledger (`server.loadAccount(address)`).
2. The account established a trustline to the asset you are going to send (check the `balances` field of the loaded account).

Another way to achieve the same result is to submit multiple transactions without waiting for the previous transaction to execute. Each ledger may contain up to 100 transactions, though I don't recommend you to send large batches at once. Send by 20-50 transactions per ledger (every 5 seconds), otherwise you may provoke fee surge pricing in the netowrk and some of your transactions will be delayed.